# VirtualBox resource usage of guest machine

Tags: virtualbox, performance

Is there any way I can measure CPU, RAM, DISK IO & other stats of Guest machine from any VirtualBox API? Means, the actual hardware stats.

I run "top" in my Ubuntu guests to read stats in real-time, but is there any other VBox API / Extensions which shows any fancy charts / line graphs or any CSV also will help to analyze.

Comment: And resource usage reports you get from within the VMs is virtual...  The host will show you how much o tthe real resources are being used by the VMs.  What is your actual goal here?  There are plenty of network/server monitoring programs out there, why not use one of them?  Also, you ask for the API, are you open to programming your own interface?  If you're just looking for a software recommendation to monitor your VMs, then this may be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @techie007, yes I am open to do programming/scripting if needed, as current Virtualbox host is showing very generic details not more than Storage & Network statistics, the more I need is CPU & RAM utilization to scale accordingly.

I tried process explorer on Windows host to measure these param, but did not help as it is showing "VirtualBox.exe" stats, but not individual guests OS.

I have searched a lot & I am not looking for a software, as this is to do something inside of VBox apis & not in the guest OS.